# How does one link NASM program to libc via ld?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I have a following program for NASM (ArchLinux i686)

```
SECTION .data
LC1: db "library call", 0

SECTION .text
extern exit
extern printf

;global main
;main:
global _start
_start:
push    LC1
call    printf

push    0
call    exit
```

Which is assembled with command:

```
nasm -f elf libcall.asm
```

If to comment two lines with `_start` and uncomment two lines with `main`, then assemble and link with the command:

```
gcc libcall.o -o libcall
```

Then the program runs OK. But if to assemble the code with `_start` entry point and link with the command:

```
ld libcall.o -o libcall -lc
```

Then after launching the program in bash (via the command `./libcall`) the following error message is returned:

```
bash: ./libcall: No such file or directory
```

Although the `libcall` file does exist. `objdump` shows the following:

```
[al libcall ]$ objdump -d libcall

libcall:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .plt:

08048190 <printf@plt-0x10>:
 8048190:   ff 35 78 92 04 08       pushl  0x8049278
 8048196:   ff 25 7c 92 04 08       jmp    *0x804927c
 804819c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

080481a0 <printf@plt>:
 80481a0:   ff 25 80 92 04 08       jmp    *0x8049280
 80481a6:   68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
 80481ab:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    8048190 <printf@plt-0x10>

080481b0 <exit@plt>:
 80481b0:   ff 25 84 92 04 08       jmp    *0x8049284
 80481b6:   68 08 00 00 00          push   $0x8
 80481bb:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmp    8048190 <printf@plt-0x10>

Disassembly of section .text:

080481c0 <_start>:
 80481c0:   68 88 92 04 08          push   $0x8049288
 80481c5:   e8 d6 ff ff ff          call   80481a0 <printf@plt>
 80481ca:   6a 00                   push   $0x0
 80481cc:   e8 df ff ff ff          call   80481b0 <exit@plt>
```

How the NASM assembly code should properly be linked with to `libc` via `ld`?

Comment: Have You tried explicitly defining the entry point? Something like `ld -o libcall -e _start libcall.o -lc`

Comment: @Kamiccolo I just tried that, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some parts of libc/crt that come in object files that you also need to link. Additionally you need to specify some options such as the dynamic loader (aka. interpreter) to use (which is probably the reason for your issue.) Just use `gcc` to do right thing for you. If you are interested you can run with `gcc -v` and then you will see the horrible command line it uses to link. You have been warned ;)

PS: you should use the `main` entry point that you have commented out.

Comment: Thanks! `ld libcall.o -o libcall -lc -e main -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2` solved the issue.